# Golang embed an interface with additional hidden methods?

Tags: http, go, interface

I want to embed a `http.ResponseWriter` in a struct. That's fine, it makes sure my struct also implements `http.ResponseWriter`:

```
type MyWriter struct {
    BytesWritten int
    http.ResponseWriter
}
```

However, it no longer implements `http.Hijacker`, `http.CloseNotifier` or `http.Flusher` even though the embedded `http.ResponseWriter` usually does.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the response writer satisfies all of the interfaces listed in the question, then you can do this:

```
type allResponseWriterInterfaces {
    http.ResponseWriter
    http.Hijacker
    http.CloseNotifier
    http.Flusher
}

type MyWriter struct {
    BytesWritten int
    allResponseWriterInterfaces
}

...

aw, ok := w.(allResponseWriterInterfaces)
if !ok {
    // oops, response writer does not implement the interfaces
    // handle the error
}
mw := MyWriter{0, aw}
```

It get's messy if the response writer does not satisfy all of the interfaces.  See [the Gorilla logger](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/1af6d56d7cd39d982856bc0cee11142baf392c52/handlers.go#L81-L95) for an example of handling the case where the response writer satisfies (http.ResponseWriter, http.CloseNotifier) or (http.ResponseWriter, http.CloseNotifier, http.Hijacker).

Comment: Yes my implementation was starting to look messy like that. Except I was also trying to optionally satisfy http.Flusher, making 8 permutations instead of 4. And I just saw that http.ResponseWriter sometimes also implements io.ReaderFrom, making what 16 permutations?

Comment: How about writing a [go generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) program to write the code for all of the permutations!  Seriously though, I am hoping that somebody answers with a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the brute-force solution. Actually implement all permutations. I tried this and found out how painful it is. There are 18 permutations!

So here is a general-purpose wrapper. The advantage is that you can re-use this wrapper as many times as you want.

The key is to define an interface like so:

```
// ResponseWriterTo can proxy requests to an underlying http.ResponseWriter.
// It is used with CustomResponseWriter to wrap an http.ResponseWriter with
// custom behavior.
type ResponseWriterTo interface {
    HeaderTo(w http.ResponseWriter) http.Header
    WriteHeaderTo(w http.ResponseWriter, s int)
    WriteTo(w http.ResponseWriter, b []byte) (n int, err error)

    // Additional methods that http.ResponseWriter sometimes implements.
    CloseNotifyTo(w http.CloseNotifier) <-chan bool
    FlushTo(w http.Flusher)
    HijackTo(w http.Hijacker) (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error)

    // ReaderFrom is used by the http package to optimize reads from TCP
    // connections or from files.
    ReadFromTo(w io.ReaderFrom, r io.Reader) (n int64, err error)
}
```

so that we can define a custom wrapper function (this is the verbose part):

```
// CustomResponseWriter creates a http.ResponseWriter that implements as many
// hidden interfaces from the base http.ResponseWriter as are available.
func CustomResponseWriter(base http.ResponseWriter, custom ResponseWriterTo) http.ResponseWriter {
    rw := &customResponseWriter{base: base, custom: custom}

    // the base http.ResponseWriter can implement many hidden interfaces,
    // so check all permutations

    type HCFR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.CloseNotifier
        http.Flusher
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HCFR); ok {
        return struct {
            HCFR
        }{rw}
    }

    type HCF interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.CloseNotifier
        http.Flusher
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HCF); ok {
        return struct {
            HCF
        }{rw}
    }

    type HCR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.CloseNotifier
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HCR); ok {
        return struct {
            HCR
        }{rw}
    }

    type HFR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.Flusher
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HFR); ok {
        return struct {
            HFR
        }{rw}
    }

    type CFR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.CloseNotifier
        http.Flusher
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(CFR); ok {
        return struct {
            CFR
        }{rw}
    }

    type HC interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.CloseNotifier
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HC); ok {
        return struct {
            HC
        }{rw}
    }

    type HF interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        http.Flusher
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HF); ok {
        return struct {
            HF
        }{rw}
    }

    type CF interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.CloseNotifier
        http.Flusher
    }
    if _, ok := base.(CF); ok {
        return struct {
            CF
        }{rw}
    }

    type HR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(HR); ok {
        return struct {
            HR
        }{rw}
    }

    type CR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.CloseNotifier
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(CR); ok {
        return struct {
            CR
        }{rw}
    }

    type FR interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Flusher
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(FR); ok {
        return struct {
            FR
        }{rw}
    }

    type H interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Hijacker
    }
    if _, ok := base.(H); ok {
        return struct {
            H
        }{rw}
    }

    type C interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.CloseNotifier
    }
    if _, ok := base.(C); ok {
        return struct {
            C
        }{rw}
    }

    type F interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        http.Flusher
    }
    if _, ok := base.(F); ok {
        return struct {
            F
        }{rw}
    }

    type R interface {
        http.ResponseWriter
        io.ReaderFrom
    }
    if _, ok := base.(R); ok {
        return struct {
            R
        }{rw}
    }

    return struct {
        http.ResponseWriter
    }{rw}
}

// customResponseWriter allows us to adapt a ResponseWriterTo to a ResponseWriter.
type customResponseWriter struct {
    base   http.ResponseWriter
    custom ResponseWriterTo
}

func (w *customResponseWriter) Header() http.Header         { return w.custom.HeaderTo(w.base) }
func (w *customResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) { return w.custom.WriteTo(w.base, b) }
func (w *customResponseWriter) WriteHeader(s int)           { w.custom.WriteHeaderTo(w.base, s) }
func (w *customResponseWriter) CloseNotify() <-chan bool {
    return w.custom.CloseNotifyTo(w.base.(http.CloseNotifier))
}
func (w *customResponseWriter) Flush() { w.custom.FlushTo(w.base.(http.Flusher)) }
func (w *customResponseWriter) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
    return w.custom.HijackTo(w.base.(http.Hijacker))
}
func (w *customResponseWriter) ReadFrom(r io.Reader) (n int64, err error) {
    return w.custom.ReadFromTo(w.base.(io.ReaderFrom), r)
}
```

The idea is to embed the correct interface into a struct. Then only the "right" methods are exposed.